# MSBuild Copy task ignores (%RecursiveDir)

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task

I have subdirectories in build output but files are copied to the root destination directory without applying `%RecursiveDir`.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <slnpath>.</slnpath>
  <binpath>.\ProjName\</binpath>
  <destination>..\..\deploy\ProjName\Master</destination>
<PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>

 <DefaultExclude Include="$(slnpath)\.\**\*.svn-base"/>
 <DefaultExclude Include="$(slnpath)\.\**\.svn\**"/>

 <DefaultExclude Include="$(slnpath)\.\**\.git\**"/>
 <DefaultExclude Include="$(slnpath)\.\**\.hg\**"/>

 <DefaultExclude Include="$(slnpath)\.\**\*.log"/>
 <DefaultExclude Include="$(slnpath)\.\**\log\*.*" />
</ItemGroup>

<CreateItem Include="$(slnpath)\$(binpath)bin\**\*.*" Exclude="@(DefaultExclude)">
  <Output ItemName="FilesToCopy" TaskParameter="Include"/>
</CreateItem>
<Copy SourceFiles="@(FilesToCopy)" 
      DestinationFiles="@(FilesToCopy->'$(destination)\bin\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')" />
```

Why it doesn't work?

Surprisingly, copying from another source directory below in the same script works:

```
<CreateItem Include="$(slnpath)\DeployOverride\All\**\*.*" Exclude="@(DefaultExclude)">
  <Output ItemName="FilesToCopy" TaskParameter="Include" /> 
</CreateItem>
<Copy SourceFiles="@(FilesToCopy)" 
      DestinationFiles="@(FilesToCopy->'$(destination)\bin\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')" />
```

Comment: I don't think there's a problem in the Copy task syntax. I copied your script, removed the DefaultExclude and changed the paths on destination and "CreateItem Include" and it worked fine for me, i would double check everything.

Comment: @user1432893 somehow the same thing in the same script works for another source directory (not $(binpath)bin\\) correctly

Comment: Can you write the example that worked? maybe through this we can figure out the issue. Also, I would strongly recommend you to use the given $(MSBuildThisFileDirectory) parameter in slnpath property and derive the next properties from this property such as: <binpath>$(slnpath)ProjName\</binpath>

Comment: @user1432893, updated with working example

Comment: Funny thing I've just noticed, $(slnpath)\$(binpath)\bin would be translated into .\.\ProjName\bin

Comment: @user1432893, yep, but it's still a correct path